# Get customer name from table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo-12

```
SELECT partner_id 
FROM parking_test  
WHERE test_date=CURRENT_DATE
```

Using this query, we get partner details who have a test today.

The customer name is present in another table `res_partner`:

```
SELECT name FROM res_partner rs
```

I have tried following code:

```
SELECT 
    name, partner_id 
FROM 
    (SELECT rs.name FROM res_partner rs) rs 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT partner_id FROM parking_test) pl ON rs.id = pl.ipartner_id 
WHERE 
    test_date = CURRENT_DATE
```

But I got an error

> ERROR: column rs.id does not exist LINE 1: ...t join (select partner_id from parking_test)pl on rs.id=pl.i...

`res_partner` table:

```
+------------+-------+
| id         | name  |
+------------+-------+
|      34567 | XYZ1  |
|      34568 | XYZ2  |
|      34569 | DDHC  |
|      34566 | DVDV  |
|      34570 | DVFDV |
|      34576 | FVFV  |
|      34567 | FVV   |
+------------+-------+
```

`parking_test` table

```
+------------+-----------+
| Partner_id | test_date |
+------------+-----------+
|      34567 | 11/06/2021|
|      34568 | 11/06/2021|
|      34569 | 12/06/2021|
|      34566 | 13/06/2021|
|      34570 | 14/06/2021|
|      34576 | 15/06/2021|
|      34567 | 16/06/2021|
+------------+-----------+
```

As we are checking current date I want to get answer as XYZ1  ,XYZ2

Comment: "by joining these" - did you try a `join` as you mentioned it in the question?

Comment: i tried..but not working ..

Comment: "not working" provides exactly no information. Please, post your code and the error message you have

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69862070/edit) your question as many times as you need to add more details. Comments is not for this. Please, move the code and error message to the question

Comment: edited the question

Comment: The error says: column `rs.id` does not exist. Can you find it in the subquery named `rs`? Tip: you do not need subqueries here, just join tables

Comment: select r.id, rs.name from res_partner rs

Comment: No its not posible..i have given demo database table in thew question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INNER JOIN and add condition in WHERE claue

-- PostgreSQL

```
SELECT rs.name, pt.partner_id
FROM res_partner rs
INNER JOIN parking_test pt
       ON rs.id = pt.partner_id
WHERE pt.test_date= CURRENT_DATE
```